# Resolve promise when multiple writeFile functions finished after for-loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

First of all, here is a part of my current code:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= variables; i++) {
            fs.writeFile("file-" + i + ".txt", dataString + ' ' + i + ' 0', "utf-8");
        }   
        if (i == variables)
            resolve('Files have been written');
        else
            reject('Some error occured');
    })
```

My problem is that I don't know how to tell my promise to resolve after all files have been written as `writeFile()` is async. What I want to do is to use these files in my next `then()` when they are completely written to my drive. Can anybody help me out here? I'm kind of lost right now and also new to node.js so please bear with me :)

Thanks in advance!

**#UPDATE 1:**

```
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= variables; i++) {
        promises.push(Promise.resolve(
            new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                fs.writeFile('file-' + i + '.cnf', dimacs2 + ' ' + i + ' 0', 'utf-8', function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
        )));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        // code that runs after files have been written
    });
```

Comment: You want `Promise.all()`

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, I already read about that, but I'm not sure how I would use this.

Comment: If you are using a promise lib like q , then make a func like `var f = q.denodeify(fs.write)` , push each fs.write in an arr which creates an array of promises and then use q.all(arr) for that . Otherwise each fs.write has a callback , create a promise for each and wait for all to resolve

Comment: @PrakashRajagaopal I'm using the native implementation of `Promise` in node.js

Comment: Ya , it does have denodeify adn all . https://github.com/then/promise or atleast i hope i am looking at the right doc :D

Comment: @PrakashRajagaopal Thanks, but I don't want to use any library as Promises are natively supported in node.js

Comment: @Since001 promise.all is in the native - it takes an array of promises.  create a promise for each writefile and resolve it in the callback. Push all the promises into an array and use Promise.all at the end

Comment: I think it wont work well. As in your promise you have closure with async function *writeFile* and *for loop*, you have to wrap for loop body into self invoked function and pass there **i** as parameter. It also helps you with your problem as you will be able to compare **i** with **variable**

Comment: @Since001 fwiw, with bluebird promises the solution is a one liner.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
Promise.all(
  variables.map(function (variable, i) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      fs.writeFile("file-" + i + ".txt", dataString + ' ' + i + ' 0', "utf-8", function (err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  })
)
.then(function () {
  // Files have been written
})
.catch(function (err) {
  // Some errors occured
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm currently trying something similar to your approach as I stated in my original post under **#Update 1**, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. Apparently, the Promises in promises array never seem to resolve and I don't know why, but I expect it has something to with my writeFile function because it actually write the files to my drive but the files itself are empty :/

Comment: @Since001 I'm pretty sure there is a rejection somewhere, that's why the then clause doesnt get called.

Comment: @hege_hegedus It actually gets called, but my output is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @Since001 That means there is an implementation error in some code you didn't show us